# How to combine two queries

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have two queries

```
1)

select Year , Month, Sum(Stores) from ABC ;

2) 
select Year, Month , Sum(SalesStores) from DEF ;
```

I want  a result like :

```
 **Year, Month , Sum(Stores), Sum(SalesStores)**
```

How can I do it ?

I tried union & Union all

```
select Year , Month, Sum(Stores) from ABC union
select Year, Month , Sum(SalesStores) from DEF ;
```

I see only 3 columns in the output

**`Year, Month Sum(Stores).`**

Here are the tables :

```
Year, Month Stores

Year Month SalesStores
```

Is there a way I can see the result in the format I would like to see ?

Comment: How are both queries related, are `ABC` and `DEF` linked via foreign key?

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't know their relationship, I prefer to use `UNION ALL`.

```
SELECT  Year, 
        Month, 
        MAX(TotalStores) TotalStores, 
        MAX(TotalSalesStores) TotalSalesStores
FROM
        (
            SELECT  Year, Month, 
                    SUM(Stores) TotalStores, 
                    NULL TotalSalesStores 
            FROM    ABC
            UNION ALL
            SELECT  Year, Month, 
                    NULL TotalStores, 
                    SUM(SalesStores) TotalSalesStores 
            from    DEF 
        ) a
GROUP   BY Year, Month
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `UNION` them in the following fashion:

```
SELECT Year , Month, Sum(Stores)  As Stores, NULL As SalesStores from ABC 

UNION

SELECT Year , Month,  NULL As Stores, Sum(Stores) As SalesStores from ABC
```

Or use `UNION ALL` if your logic allows it.

Comment: hmmm... Is there a way to remove all the extra nulls. I see nulls when I try this method

Comment: Yes, it's possible. When you calculate your `sum`s, do you do over your entire tables or by month of a year?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT Year, Month, SUM(TotalStores) as TotalAllStores, SUM(TotalSalesStore) as TotalAllSalesStore
FROM
(
 SELECT Year , Month, Sum(Stores) as TotalStores, 0 as TotalSalesStore from ABC union
 UNION ALL
 SELECT Year, Month , 0 as TotalStores, Sum(SalesStores) as TotalSalesStore from DEF 
) SalesByYearMonth
GROUP BY Year, Month
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use [FULL OUTER JOIN](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187518%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) thus:

```
SELECT ISNULL(x.[Year], y.[Year]) AS [Year],
ISNULL(x.[Month], y.[Month]) AS [Month],
x.Sum_Stores,
y.Sum_SalesStores
FROM (select Year , Month, Sum(Stores) AS Sum_Stores from ABC ...) AS x
FULL OUTER JOIN (select Year, Month , Sum(SalesStores) AS Sum_SalesStores from DEF ...) AS y
ON x.[Year] = y.[Year] AND x.[Month] = y.[Month]
```